# Update Xterm Title Bar with Conda environment prefix

Tags: bash, python, environment-variables

I wanted to update my gnome terminal tabs to indicate the conda environment that was active in that terminal. I typically have many tabs and a few environments activate at once, so finding the right tab was frustrating.

Conda updates the prompt (by pre-pending the environment prefix to the prompt) when switching into an environment via `source activate environment-prefix` and restores the prompt when deactivating the environment with `conda deactivate`.

However, there didn't seem to be a way to force conda to update the [xterm title bar](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/xterm-title-bar-manipulations.html) when it updates the prompt. There didn't seem to be a way to edit the activate script that would stick after an update. Also, following the logic of the conda and activate scripts did not provide an obvious place to add this capability (at least that I could figure out). An older post from 2017 that I can no longer find mentioned this issue, but the solution to edit the activate script didn't seem to be applicable any longer and my searching found no solution.

I want a solution that will work automatically and not alter other parts of the prompt, be available in all of my terminals/shells (on the subject host), and work seamlessly with conda.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was creating a function in my .bashrc file. The function runs the normal conda activate script which adds the environment to the prompt as usual. The function then edits the prompt variable to add the environment into the Xterm Title Bar.

The benefit is that the normal conda activate script runs unaltered and the `conda deactivate` script undoes the effect, even the change in the Xterm title bar.

Here is the function definition from the .bashrc file, more details on its design below.

```
# function to replace a call to the activate script in conda and set 
#+ Xterm title bar to include environment by
#+ replacing "source activate" with the following "activate" function

activate () {
# run the normal conda activate script first
#+ passing all arguments
    . activate $* 

# the activate script creates some Anaconda variables, including
# CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER which has the environment prefix in parens
# create a couple of temporary variables

    preX='\\[\\e\]0\;'
    Xrepl="\[\e]0;${CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER} "
# no need to test for xterm, since no match if no xterm title bar
# no need to check for no matches, since PS1 will remain unchanged

    PS1=${PS1/${preX}/${Xrepl}}
}
```

To use the function and activate a given environment, simply type
`activate env-name`. This functionality mirrors the Windows install of Anaconda where environments are activated directly by running a script (without "source"ing it).

Line by line:

`. activate $*`

This line runs the activate script that is installed by default by Anaconda. Anaconda also adds its own bin directory to the path, so there is no need to fully qualify the location. The $* includes all function arguments and sends them to the activate script.

`preX='\\[\\e\]0\;'`

This variable holds the escape sequences that define the beginning of the Xterm Title Bar in the prompt variable (PS1). The escape sequences for the Xterm Title Bar I got from [Chapter 6.3. Xterm Title Bar Manipulations](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/xterm-title-bar-manipulations.html). The details about the prompt variable and its components I got from [The Bash Prompt HOWTO](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/). Also, this forum thread was a great resource initially: [Changing colors for user, host, directory information in terminal command prompt](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123268/changing-colors-for-user-host-directory-information-in-terminal-command-prompt)

The single quotes in the variable definition keep the characters from being interpreted once but the backslashes, brackets, and semicolon need to be escaped because they are evaluated in the search expression below. I had to figure this one out by trial and (lots of) error. I understand this is one of the more complicated aspects of bash.

`Xrepl="\[\e]0;${CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER} "`

This variable holds the replacement for the escape sequence. Since the escape sequence itself is replaced (see below), it needed to be included in the replacement text, but for some reason, this variable is not evaluated so the additional escaping in `preX` was not required.

The `CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER` variable is inserted into the environment by the activate script and includes the environment prefix between parentheses.

`PS1=${PS1/${preX}/${Xrepl}}`

Finally, the work is done here. This is a "simple" [bash string manipulation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). The `preX` variable contents are searched for within the `PS1` variable. If they are found, they are replaced with the contents of the `Xrepl` variable. If they are not found, no change is made to the prompt. This effet allows this function to not have to make sure that the terminal is an xterm.

The amazing thing is that when `conda deactivate` is run, it removes both the prefix from the prompt as well as the inserted environment from the Xterm Title Bar. I imagine that this is because it just cached the original prompt, but I don't know for sure.

I hope this helps someone. It was a learning experience for me because I was not very familiar with the capabilities of bash and scripting. Not to mention the details of the prompt and all that can be done with it.